# Remove first line if blank using RegEx in YML file

Tags: regex, yaml

I'm running a script to grab text from websites, but the current code sometimes has the output start with a blank line.

> data1 data2 data3
>
> data4 data5 data6
>
> data7 data8 data9

I also have other files that don't have a blank line to start.

Running this regex script on all the files at once, how can I remove the first line of the file **only if** the first line is blank, while keeping the blank lines in the middle of the files?

I am using regex in a yml config file.

Comment: How does your "regex script" look like?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following regex to match if file's first line is blank:

```
^\s*$
```

**together with two regex flags** - multiline (*m*) and Anchored (*A*).

Explanation:

```
^     # line start 
\s*   # match between 0 and unlimited amount of whitespace chars
$     # end of line
```

The Anchored flag allows to match only the first line, rather than all blank lines.

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/P9HSmp/2) here.